# Ruby [How to get last History Record from Date Object]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have **Tables**

> Order

```
+-----+----------+------+-----------+------------+
| id  | id_reff  | pay0  | last_pay  |    date    |
+-----+----------+------+-----------+------------+
|  9  | 0110123  |   7  |        6  | 2017-10-20 |
|  8  | 0110123  |   6  |        5  | 2017-10-19 |
|  6  | 0110123  |   5  |        4  | 2017-10-15 |
|  5  | 0110123  |   4  |        3  | 2017-10-12 |
|  3  | 0110123  |   3  |        2  | 2017-10-08 |
|  2  | 0110123  |   2  |        1  | 2017-10-01 |
+-----+----------+------+-----------+------------+
```

> customer

```
+----+---------+------+
| id | id_reff| name |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 | 110123 | jon  | <<<
|  2 | 110124 | jin  |
|  3 | 110125 | jun  |
|  4 | 110126 | jan  |
|  5 | 110127 | jack |
|  6 | 110128 | jick |
+----+---------+------+
```

> Controller : customers_controller.rb

```
def get_history
  render json: {
       customer: Customer.find_by(id_reff: params[:id_reff]),
       bill: Order.where(id_reff: params[:id_reff]).last
end
```

> Order _Form.rb

```
pay0 :
last_pay : <get from previous pay0>
etc
etc
```

**issue :**
if i create **new** OR **edit** any **Order** , action .last give me this

```
customer:  | 1 | 110123 | jon |

bill: | 9 | 0110123 | 7 |  6 | 2017-10-20 |
```

=========

```
if i edit : order[id: 8][date: 2017-10-19]
i should get
    >> order.date = 2017-10-15 ; order.pay0 = 5
    
or

if i edit order[id: 5][date: 2017-10-12] 
i should get
    >> order.date = 2017-10-08 ; order.pay0 = 3
```

=========

> please help me to rebuild **get_history** action in customers_controller.rb
>
> rails 4.2.3
>
> ruby 2.3.3

Comment: what variable contains the updated order instance or at least it's `id`?

Comment: Why aren't you relating these via A:R relations?

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke `.last` it will return the record with the higher id.

In your specific case, you could add a custom scope to your `Order` model such as:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  scope :most_recent, ->() { order(date: :desc).first }
end
```

The only change you will have to implement is:

```
def get_history
  render json: {
       customer: Customer.find_by(id_reff: params[:id_reff]),
       bill: Order.where(id_reff: params[:id_reff]).most_recent
end
```

Note that this solution would working assuming that you will have only one order per `id_reff` per date

For further explanation, try to have a look at [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) in Rails Documentation

Answer (score 0):

> if i edit : order[id: 8][date: 2017-10-19]

Assuming that you have access to `order`'s `id` and `date`, you can have a scope like this

```
scope :previous_order, -> { order(date: :desc).first }
```

Then you can call it in your controller

```
Order.where('date <= ? and id != ?', params[:date], params[:id]).previous_order
```